# How can I find and reserve an available port for a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, udp

I'm trying to construct two components that communicate via UDP sockets. Component 1 is in the main thread and Component 2 is in a secondary thread. Multiple copies of this application can be running on the same machine at the same time, so I can't used fixed ports. The program also needs to be run on both Windows and Linux.

I've been trying to do this by binding 2 QUdpSockets specifying the port as 0 (asking Qt to choose a free port for me). I then pass the first QUdpSocket and the second socket's parameters to component 1, giving it all it needs to send and receive. For Component 2, I don't think I can pass the QUdpSocket across the thread boundary, so I pass only parameters and construct + bind the socket in the secondary thread.

However, the binding of the socket in the secondary thread fails. Presumably because there's already the socket in the main thread bound to the same port.

Is there any way I can resolve this while still knowing both ports prior to constructing either object?

Comment: Just a thought, but you could always set up the communication pipe *before* you fork into two threads. Depends on when you create the second thread though.

Comment: I don't understand " I don't think I can pass the QUdpSocket across the thread boundary" and although not an expert with Qt don't think it's true.  If it's just a resource (a class instance) then it has no affinity to a particular thread.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using sockets to communicate between two threads in the same application?  You can certainly do that, but socket communication is usually reserved for *inter*process communication, not *intra*process communication.  This seems like an overly complicated way to communicate between threads.

Comment: @Matt Davis: The two components are normally full applications in their own right, and may reside on separate machines. For some testing, I'm combining the two into a single process, since it's a little easier to set up than a multi-process test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think I can pass the QUdpSocket across the thread boundary

You can, so do that. Just don't use it in both your threads simultaneously .

Comment: That is awesome news. I'm rather new to multithreading and sockets, so their intersection has me somewhat confused. Let me just try it out..

Comment: Perfect. There were a couple things I had to keep in mind: moving the QUdpSocket into the correct thread with QObject::moveToThread, and I was briefly tripped up by sockets sometimes coming into the component with data already inside of them. But it worked out beautifully in the end.